# Is this possible to install R on my hosting and execute there shiny app, so It could show on my domain?

Tags: r, web, shiny, hosting

I'm trying to public my Shiny app and I can do it with shinyapps.io, but I'm forecasting, that there will be pretty high traffic. Shinyapps pricing is pretty high, so I'm wondering if it is possible to run shiny app directly from my hosting (attached to my domain) and if yes - how to do this. The thing is, that I want to use also wordpress design and shiny app only one one of the subpages.

Answer (score 0):

I have not published my shiny application in a web hosting environmet. All I have done so far is just publishing my shiny application in my company server. It does not have any DNS server. Nevertheles, it can be accessed from outside on the internet using a browser by calling the server's public IP address followed by the 3838 port number and my shiny application's name. It was a small application for internal client use. I asked the administrator of the server to install everything I need related with R server and shiny package. I developed my shiny app locally. After I satisfied, I ask the administrator to copy my shiny application folder containing app.R file to /srv/shiny-server directory. It is an Ubuntu OS server. Once R server and shiny package is installed, it can serve the hosting. Shiny application needs to be placed in /srv/shiny-server directory so it also needs an administrator previlege. To do so, I do not pay a cost at all. It is free. If you have any web name, I believe you can also publish your application replacing the call to the IP address as what I do. FYI, rmarkdown also facilitates blog-like report with shiny widgets attachment as in https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/2671/Combining-Shiny-R-Markdown.html